# Return Duplicate value Postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

```
    with
 cte1 as(
    select sts.user_id,u.username,sts.target,sts.from_date,sts.to_date
    from sales_target_settings sts
    left join users u on sts.user_id=u.id
    order by sts.id
            ),
     cte2 as (
            select count(*) as tot,se.assign_to_id 
    from sales_enquiry se
    left join cte1 on se.assign_to_id=cte1.user_id 
    where se.enq_date between cte1.from_date and cte1.to_date
    group by se.assign_to_id)  

    select cte1.user_id,cte1.username,cte1.target,cte1.from_date,cte1.to_date,coalesce(cte2.tot,0) as total,case when (cte1.target-coalesce(cte2.tot,0))>0 then cte1.target-coalesce(cte2.tot,0) else 0 end as balance
    from cte1 left join cte2 on cte1.user_id=cte2.assign_to_id
    order by cte1.username ;
```

OUTPUT[image: OUTPUT]

First table  `sales_target_settings' columns`user_idtarget`,`from_date`,`to_date`

Second table `sales_enquiry` columns `enq_date`,`assign_to_id`.

I want total enquiry count for each user where enquiry date between from_date and to_date from the table `sales_target_settings`.

From the output for user id `111` both total value is `6` . Actually the date between `2016-10-01` and `2016-10-31` the total value for user `111` `6` is correct but date between `2016-09-01` and `2016-09-30` total value is `0`. How to solve this issue. I think the query not checking the date between `2016-09-01` to `2016-09-30` for user `111`

Comment: Very hard to help if you don't describe the tables involved and don't provide the data being queried. See: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4955425).

Comment: Please add the information as an edit to your question instead of in the comments. This will allow you to format the information in a more readable way.

Comment: Note: `order by sts.id` in a CTE or subquery makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the sql query, here are my observation

```
with cte1 as(
select sts.user_id,u.username,sts.target,sts.from_date,sts.to_date
from sales_target_settings sts
left join users u on sts.user_id=u.id
order by sts.id ),

 ------------------------------------------- this cte1 is returning two rows with two different from_date and to_date for userid = 111
 cte2 as (
        select count(*) as tot,se.assign_to_id , 
-------------------------------------------- add cte1.from_date, cte1.to_date to cte2
        cte1.from_date, cte1.to_date
-------------
from sales_enquiry se
left join cte1 on se.assign_to_id=cte1.user_id 
where se.enq_date between cte1.from_date and cte1.to_date
group by se.assign_to_id,cte1.from_date, cte1.to_date)  

-------------------------------------------- this cte2 is returning one row for 111

select cte1.user_id,cte1.username,cte1.target,cte1.from_date,cte1.to_date,coalesce(cte2.tot,0) as total,case when (cte1.target-coalesce(cte2.tot,0))>0 then cte1.target-coalesce(cte2.tot,0) else 0 end as balance
from 

------------------------------------------ You are joining cte1 and cte2 only the basis of user_id. Instead of doing that add two more condition two join those cte1 and cte2
cte1 
left join cte2 on 
cte1.user_id=cte2.assign_to_id
and cte1.from_date = cte2.from_date
and cte1.to_date = cte2.to_date

order by cte1.username ;
```

Comment: Did you try the above query which I have written ?

Comment: Yes..But no use

Comment: Could you please explain what is issue with that query ? if it is possible for you to paste the output that query.

Comment: no worries. it happens. its my pleasure to solve your problem.

Comment: @ Fahad Anjum Thank you